# Subtract dates on different lags

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a dataset with two columns, `Date1` and `Date2`. My goal is to subtract date2 from date1 at lag 0, lag 1, lag 2, ..., lag 6. If date2 is bigger, then flag it as 1 otherwise 0. I need to do this iteratively so

*date2[0] - date1[0] date1[1] ... date1[5]*

*date2[1] - date1[1] date1[2] ... date1[6]*

etc.

```
                Date1               Date2
0  2021-06-15 00:25:29 2021-06-15 10:05:50
1  2021-06-15 13:32:01 2021-06-15 14:17:30
2  2021-06-15 17:59:37 2021-06-15 18:12:30
3  2021-06-17 01:01:16 2021-06-17 13:30:23
4  2021-06-17 14:07:11 2021-06-17 14:34:45
5  2021-06-17 18:30:24 2021-06-17 19:22:02
6  2021-06-17 19:42:28 2021-06-18 10:11:04
7  2021-06-18 12:54:50 2021-06-18 13:25:16
8  2021-06-18 16:59:40 2021-06-18 17:22:23
9  2021-06-18 17:49:54 2021-06-18 18:25:53
10 2021-06-18 19:57:39 2021-06-18 20:43:11
11 2021-06-21 13:52:28 2021-06-21 14:03:31
12 2021-06-21 15:44:46 2021-06-21 18:31:21
13 2021-06-21 20:03:37 2021-06-21 20:59:54
14 2021-06-22 18:39:22 2021-06-22 19:23:28
15 2021-06-23 19:45:54 2021-06-23 19:52:26
16 2021-06-23 19:59:33 2021-06-23 20:00:43
17 2021-06-24 12:53:31 2021-06-25 13:25:30
18 2021-06-25 17:57:05 2021-06-25 19:32:37
19 2021-06-28 13:34:25 2021-06-28 14:00:04
```

**DATA**

> {'Date1': {0: Timestamp('2021-06-15 00:25:29'), 1: Timestamp('2021-06-15 13:32:01'), 2: Timestamp('2021-06-15 17:59:37'), 3: Timestamp('2021-06-17 01:01:16'), 4: Timestamp('2021-06-17 14:07:11'), 5: Timestamp('2021-06-17 18:30:24'), 6: Timestamp('2021-06-17 19:42:28'), 7: Timestamp('2021-06-18 12:54:50'), 8: Timestamp('2021-06-18 16:59:40'), 9: Timestamp('2021-06-18 17:49:54'), 10: Timestamp('2021-06-18 19:57:39'), 11: Timestamp('2021-06-21 13:52:28'), 12: Timestamp('2021-06-21 15:44:46'), 13: Timestamp('2021-06-21 20:03:37'), 14: Timestamp('2021-06-22 18:39:22'), 15: Timestamp('2021-06-23 19:45:54'), 16: Timestamp('2021-06-23 19:59:33'), 17: Timestamp('2021-06-24 12:53:31'), 18: Timestamp('2021-06-25 17:57:05'), 19: Timestamp('2021-06-28 13:34:25')}, 'Date2': {0: Timestamp('2021-06-15 10:05:50'), 1: Timestamp('2021-06-15 14:17:30'), 2: Timestamp('2021-06-15 18:12:30'), 3: Timestamp('2021-06-17 13:30:23'), 4: Timestamp('2021-06-17 14:34:45'), 5: Timestamp('2021-06-17 19:22:02'), 6: Timestamp('2021-06-18 10:11:04'), 7: Timestamp('2021-06-18 13:25:16'), 8: Timestamp('2021-06-18 17:22:23'), 9: Timestamp('2021-06-18 18:25:53'), 10: Timestamp('2021-06-18 20:43:11'), 11: Timestamp('2021-06-21 14:03:31'), 12: Timestamp('2021-06-21 18:31:21'), 13: Timestamp('2021-06-21 20:59:54'), 14: Timestamp('2021-06-22 19:23:28'), 15: Timestamp('2021-06-23 19:52:26'), 16: Timestamp('2021-06-23 20:00:43'), 17: Timestamp('2021-06-25 13:25:30'), 18: Timestamp('2021-06-25 19:32:37'), 19: Timestamp('2021-06-28 14:00:04')}}

Comment: it may need nested `for`-loops `for i in range(len(data)-1): for j in range(i, len(data)): ...`

Comment: @furas Can you help me do this? I am very junior and been stuck here for a while

Comment: @Beck What's your expected output?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma For every Date2, just the sum of how many of those 6 Date1 are smaller than it

Comment: @Beck I think you meant 7 `Date1`? because `lag0 ... lag6` would be 7 dates.

Comment: You are correct. lag0 to lag5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Setup

```
print(df)

                Date1               Date2
0 2021-06-14 00:25:29 2021-06-15 10:05:50
1 2021-06-09 13:32:01 2021-06-15 14:17:30
2 2021-06-12 17:59:37 2021-06-15 18:12:30
3 2021-06-17 01:01:16 2021-06-17 13:30:23
4 2021-06-14 14:07:11 2021-06-17 14:34:45
5 2021-06-12 18:30:24 2021-06-17 19:22:02
6 2021-06-11 19:42:28 2021-06-18 10:11:04
7 2021-06-17 12:54:50 2021-06-18 13:25:16
8 2021-06-18 16:59:40 2021-06-18 17:22:23
9 2021-06-15 17:49:54 2021-06-18 18:25:53
```

##### Numpy solution

```
x = df['Date1'].to_numpy()
y = df['Date2'].to_numpy()

m = y[:, None] >= x
df['count'] = (np.triu(m) & ~np.triu(m, 6)).sum(1)
```

##### Result

```
                Date1               Date2  count
0 2021-06-14 00:25:29 2021-06-15 10:05:50      5
1 2021-06-09 13:32:01 2021-06-15 14:17:30      5
2 2021-06-12 17:59:37 2021-06-15 18:12:30      4
3 2021-06-17 01:01:16 2021-06-17 13:30:23      5
4 2021-06-14 14:07:11 2021-06-17 14:34:45      5
5 2021-06-12 18:30:24 2021-06-17 19:22:02      4
6 2021-06-11 19:42:28 2021-06-18 10:11:04      3
7 2021-06-17 12:54:50 2021-06-18 13:25:16      2
8 2021-06-18 16:59:40 2021-06-18 17:22:23      2
9 2021-06-15 17:49:54 2021-06-18 18:25:53      1
```

##### Some details

- `y[:, None] >= x` creates a boolean mask by comparing each value in `Date2` to every value in `Date1`
- `np.triu(arr, k=0)` is used to select an array with the elements below the `k`-th diagonal zeroed.

Comment: This is impressive! Numpy is so powerful. Now If I want to keep the same dataframe format, I just merge this result back to my original df ?

Comment: @Beck This will not change the dataframe format since we are already assigning a column named `count` to the original dataframe so there is absolutely no need to merge.